# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

Hi I'm trying to compile a simple jsp file with tomcat but I kept having this error message

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 13 in the jsp file: /WebContent/test.jsp
Member cannot be resolved to a type
10: <body>
11: <%  
12:     //MyBatisDao myDao = new MyBatisDao();
13:     List<Member> list; // = myDao.func("test");
14:     //out.println("Result list= " + list);
15: %>
16: </body>
```

test.jsp (at Webcontent)

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="pageNumber.*, java.util.*, java.io.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html> 
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%  
    List<Member> list;
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Member.java

```
package pageNumber;
public class Member {
 private String id;
 private String pw;
 private int point;
 private int lvl;

 public Member() {}
 public Member(String id, String pw, int point, int lvl) {
  this.id = id;
  this.pw = pw;
  this.point = point;
  this.lvl = lvl;
 }

 public String getId() { return id; }
 public void setId(String id) { this.id = id; }
 public String getPw() { return pw; }
 public void setPw(String pw) { this.pw = pw; }
 public int getPoint() { return point; }
 public void setPoint(int point) { this.point = point; }     
 public int getLvl() { return lvl; }
 public void setLvl(int lvl) { this.lvl = lvl; }
 public String toString() {
  return "ID= " + id + ", PW= " + pw + ", POINT= " + point + ", LVL= " + lvl;
 }
```

}

As far as I can tell, I am having this problem because my tomcat cannot locate the class file, 
so I have placed my class files at

- build/classes/pageNumber (where pageNumber is my package name)
- WEB-INF/classes/pageNumber
- tomcat\work\Catalina\localhost_\org\apache\jsp\pageNumber

but none of it worked out.
Any help?

---

Edit:
After I change my import declaration from

```
<%@ page import="pageNumber.*, java.util.*, java.io.*" %>
```

to

```
<%@ page import="java.util.List, pageNumber.Member" %>
```

It actually gave me a new type of error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 15 in the generated java file
Only a type can be imported. pageNumber.Member resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: 12 in the jsp file: /WebContent/test.jsp
Member cannot be resolved to a type
9: </head>
10: <body>
11: <%  
12:     List<Member> list; // = myDao.func("test");
13: %>
14: </body>
15: </html>
```

Comment: Do you have a `package` declaration in "Member.java"?

Comment: if you use a external .jar; save it in WEB-INF/lib

Answer (score 12):

This maybe caused by jar conflict. Remove the servlet-api.jar in your servlet/WEB-INF/ directory, %Tomcat home%/lib already have this lib.

Comment: After removing servlet-api.jar 
Tomcat stop working. After replacing it it worked but same error occured

Comment: Really Help me :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused because you need to import the `pageNumber.Member` class in your JSP. Make sure to also include another packages and classes like `java.util.List`.

```
<%@ page import="pageNumber.*, java.util.*" %>
```

Still, you have a major problem by **using scriptlets in your JSP**. Refer to [How to avoid Java Code in JSP-Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/1065197) and start practicing [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) and [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) and focusing more on a MVC solution instead.

Comment: I'm not sure about your point, Luiggi. I said that I already added pageNumber.Member and java.util.List but that still gave me errors.

Comment: @MartinYang I've tried to reproduce your exact problem by having a `pageNumber.Member` class where `pageNumber` is the package name, then creating a `test.jsp` page in the main web pages folder (e.g. WebContent) and a scriptlet (against my taste) with `<% List<Member> list; %>. I added <%@ page import="pageNumber.Member, java.util.List" %> before the `<html>`, build the project and deployed it, and worked like a charm. Probably there's something more that you're not telling us. Try to clean your environment, rebuild your project and deploy it.

Comment: Did you set up a "special" configuration for Eclipse or tomcat? b/c no matter what I do, it just doesn't seem to be compiled in my comp.

Comment: @MartinYang nope, just a clean Java Web Project with your actual configuration. Probably you have something else that you're not showing in your question. I suggest you to create a new web project and replicate this behavior. If you have problems with it, edit your question for further guidance.

Comment: I created a new dynamic web project, created two files, Member.java and test.jsp and imported Member.java to test.jsp, but I still got exact same error message.

Answer (score 0):

include your Member Class to your jsp :

```
<%@ page import="pageNumber.*, java.util.*, java.io.*,yourMemberPackage.Member" %>
```

Comment: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to find taglib [bean] for URI: [/tags/struts-bean] . Unable to fix this error

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to manually put class files on Tomcat. Just make sure your package declaration for `Member` is correctly defined as

```
package pageNumber;
```

since, that's the only application package you're importing in your JSP.

```
<%@ page import="pageNumber.*, java.util.*, java.io.*" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the servlet jar from web project,as any how, the application/web server already had.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the issue, i found that that older ecj library is present in Apache Tomcat directory 
1)remove old jar from Apache Tomcat  library 
2)clean the project 
3)build it. 
It started working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Project -> Properties -> Project Facets**.

Check for the **Java** version, make sure it should be the same as your JDK version.
Restart the server.

Comment: `Window > Preferences > Installed JREs` on Eclipse

Answer (score -1):

This line of yours:

```
<%@ page import="pageNumber.*, java.util.*, java.io.*" %>
```

Requires an `@` symbol before `%` like this:

```
<%@ page import="pageNumber.*, java.util.*, java.io.*" @%>
```